# Adjust for variable in mixed effects model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I've looked at prior posts as well as the lme4 documentation in R but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I am trying to model how an intervention (tutoring), impacts examination pass rates for students.  I have 500 students, who all take 30 exams.  Passing an exam is a binary event (0/1). After 20 exams, all students who have failed at least 8 exams received mandatory tutoring, done once.  I am trying to model whether this tutoring increases the "pass rate" of future examinations for these students.

I believe this is best modeled with a mixed effects model, with students being a random variable, and "was tutored" a binary variable.

The trouble I am having is how to bring in the actual examination itself into the model, since the pass rates for each exam vary and are not truly "random" since each is different and thus of different complexity.  Additionally, students get better at passing the examinations, in general, over time, controlling for complexity (we have shown this), regardless of tutoring.

Reproducible example:

```
library("tidyr")
library("lme4")

# Setup data
students <- paste0("student", seq(1, 500, by=1))
exams_pre <- replicate(15,rbinom(500, 1, 0.75))
exams_post <- replicate(15,rbinom(500, 1, 0.75))
all_exams <- as.data.frame(cbind(students, exams_pre, exams_post))
colnames(all_exams) <- c("student", seq(1:30))

# Tidy
all_exams_wide <- all_exams %>% gather(exam, passed, -student) %>% mutate(exam = as.integer(exam), passed = as.integer(passed))

# Label each student:test row with whether the student had been tutored at the time of that test
received_tutoring <- all_exams_wide %>% filter(exam < 20 & passed == 0) %>% group_by(student) %>% summarise(failed = n()) %>% filter(failed >= 8)
all_exams_wide <- all_exams_wide %>% mutate(was_tutored = ifelse(exam >= 20 & student %in% received_tutoring$student, 1, 0))
```

Now I can get the underlying complexity for each examination by looking at the pass rate for that exam among the students who did not require tutoring, and add that as another variable for each student:examination pair:

```
# Bring in baseline pass rates for each examination
baseline_exam_pass_rates <- all_exams_wide %>% filter(!student %in% received_tutoring$student) %>% group_by(exam) %>% summarise(pass_rate = sum(as.integer(passed)) / n())
all_exams_wide <- all_exams_wide %>% left_join(baseline_exam_pass_rates, by="exam")
```

And then create a data set that only includes students that were tutored:

```
# Create data set of JUST students that needed tutoring
all_exams_only_tutored <- all_exams_wide %>% filter(student %in% received_tutoring$student)
```

My question is whether I am thinking about this correctly (mixed effects model) and if so, how to bring in the examinations.  How do we model whether this tutoring intervention improves pass rates for those that have failed a bunch before?

My attempt at this, though I do not think this is correct since intuitively, exam should be adjusted by the underlying pass rate:

```
model <- glmer(passed ~ was_tutored + (1 | student) + (1 | exam), 
               data=all_exams_only_tutored, 
               family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Thank you in advance!